# Inserting into newly created table elements using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I currently have working code that inserts rows into a table. It looks like this:

```
<script type= "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var new_row = '<td><input type="text" value="Type question here" /></td><td><input type="button"class="add_next" value=" + " /><input type="button" class="move_up" value=" ^ " /><input type="button" class="move_down" value=" v " /><input type="button" class="remove" value=" x " /></td>';

    var q_num = 2; // question number

    $('.add_next').click(function() {

        console.log(this);

        console.log(($('<tr>')).insertAfter($(this).closest('tr'))
                    .attr('id', 'Q'+q_num)
                    .attr('name', 'Q'+q_num)
                    .append(new_row)

            );
        q_num++;

    });
});
</script>
```

My problem here that the variable new_row is ugly. I would like to use $.append($('')), .attr() and other jQuery functions to create this row on-the-fly but I have not come up with a way of doing it. The best I could come up with was this:

```
($('<tr>')).insertAfter($(this).closest('tr'))
                    .append($('<td>'))
                        .append('<input type="text" value="Type question here" />')
                    .append($('<td>'))
                        .append('<input type="button"class="add_next" value=" + " />')
                        .append('<input type="button" class="move_up" value=" ^ " />')
                        .append('<input type="button" class="move_down" value=" v " />')
                        .append('<input type="button" class="remove" value=" x " />');
```

How do I make this same entry using jQuery instead of a block of valid HTML?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do something like that:

```
var new_row = $('<tr/>',{'id':'Q'+q_num,'name':'Q'+q_num}).append(
    $('<td/>').append(
        $('<input/>',{'type':'text','value':'Type question here'})
    ),
    $('<td/>').append(
        $('<input/>',{'type':'button','value':' + ','class':'add_next'}),
        $('<input/>',{'type':'button','value':' ^ ','class':'move_up'}),
        $('<input/>',{'type':'button','value':' v ','class':'move_down'}),
        $('<input/>',{'type':'button','value':' x ','class':'remove'})
    ),
);
```

then change your insert code to:

```
$(this).closest('tr').after(new_row);
```

Comment: The problem with this is that inserts rows inside of other rows.

Comment: @JordWms yes you have to modify your insert code a bit. i updated my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
.append('<input type="button"class="add_next" value=" + " />')
```

you could

```
.append($('<input />').attr({
    'class': 'add_next',
    'type': 'button',
    'value': ''
}));
```

Comment: Thank you for this reply. I will be sure to remember it. Is there a reason to use ($('<input />')).append() instead of $('<input>').append() or is that just a styling choice?

Comment: That's the convention of the jQuery documentation.